# Complexity of Untwisting Polygons

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry

What is the complexity of the following task:
given a sequence $p_1, ..., p_n, p_1$ that defines a closed polyline in the euclidean plane,
what is the complexity of finding a reordering of the points, that resembles a simple polygon?
To clarify: the task is to find a suitable reordering as fast as possible; it is not the task to find a reordering that resembles a simple polygon that is optimal in some respect.

The measure of complexity shall be the number of vertex-swaps.

Edit:

I am looking for algorithms (and their complexities) that transform any closed polyline into a simple polygon by a minimal number of vertex-swaps, using no extra memory and only the ability to detect and remove edge-intersection via vertex-swaps.
The task is somehow related to sorting if one interpretes intersections as inversions and it would be interesting to see, whether the analogy allows the successful adaptation of sorting algorithms.

Comment: Is there a general position assumption we can make about the p_i?

Comment: the only restriction is, that the points are pairwise distinct. If there are however special situations which allow for faster algorithms, that would be welcome, too. My main intent is to generate "random" simple polygons as quick as possible.

Comment: This paper is close to your interests, and might help: Aloupis, Greg, Prosenjit Bose, Erik D. Demaine, Stefan Langerman, Henk Meijer, Mark Overmars, and Godfried T. Toussaint. "Computing signed permutations of polygons." *International Journal of Computational Geometry & Applications* 21, no. 01 (2011): 87-100.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke thanks for the reference; it is also available online and seems to be a very close fit.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to have been a very popular topic 15-20 years ago. Cf.
http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/open/randompoly.html
(dated 1999).

I suppose no real progress has been made since then.

Comment: but my problem has a polynomial solution: while there are pairs of intersecting edges, remove one of the intersections by inverting an appropriate sequence of edges. A straightforward implementation takes O(n^4) swaps. There should however be more intelligent ways of removing the intersections. Sometimes intersections can be removed by swapping a pair of vertices instead of inverting a whole sequence or, maybe looking for edges with the most intersections helps in improving performance.

Comment: I'm not sure it's not better to forget all the edges and just construct a polygon directly.

Comment: generating random polygons is a different story then; they care about the uniformity, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the question, but I'll give a naive answer.

We are given an initial cyclic order $\phi$, so if we know of a cyclic order $\psi$ that produces a simple polygon, we can ask how many vertex-swaps are necessary to pass from $\phi$ to $\psi$.  If you require vertex-swaps to be between adjacent elements, then this is bounded above by $n^2/2$ or so - this is a cyclic version of the usual bubblesort bound.  If you allow vertex-swaps to be arbitrary transpositions, then this is bounded above by $n-1$.

One way to compute a satisfactory order $\psi$ is to take the lower convex envelope of the point set, oriented clockwise, then lexicographically order the remaining points, first by $x$-coordinate, then $y$-coordinate.

Comment: The questions is to remove the intersections from a given closed polyline with the least number of vertex swaps. Costructing a simple polygon from a point-set is fairly simple using Graham scan. I not much interested in worst-case bounds; I would like algorithms that "analyze" the problem instance in some way in trying to determine the optimal sequence of swaps.

Comment: @ManfredWeis I see.  This sort of information belongs in the statement of your question.  You had mentioned an $O(n^4)$ bound in a different comment, so I thought it was worthwhile to point out that better bounds are not hard to find.